# Random shape generator in Java

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, shapes

I am trying to build a program where at least 10 shapes are created randomly and are given random places. So far I have this:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RandomShapeViewer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
        final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;

        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setTitle("RandomShapeViewer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        RandomShapesComponent component = new RandomShapesComponent();
        frame.add(component);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class RandomShapesComponent extends JComponent
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        RandomShapeGenerator r = new RandomShapeGenerator(getWidth(), getHeight());

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
           g2.draw(r.Graphics());
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class RandomShapeGenerator {

    int width, height;
    Random ran = new Random();

    public RandomShapeGenerator(int i, int j)
    {
        int width = i;
        int height = j;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        switch(ran.nextInt(10)) {
            default:
            case 0:   g.drawOval(10, 20, 10, 20);
            case 1:   g.drawLine(100, 100, 150, 150);
            case 2:   g.drawRect(30,40,30,40);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have a couple of questions:

1. Is it possible to draw multiple lines in one case (and thus creating a triangle) and if so how would I go about doing this?
2. I also get this error message:
       1 error found:
       File: D:\Downloads\Wallpaper\RandomShapesComponent.java  [line: 14]
       Error: cannot find symbol
         symbol:   method Graphics()
         location: variable r of type RandomShapeGenerator
3. Furthermore a follow-up question on my first question: how would I be able to fill in the Oval and Rectangle, etc. with a solid color?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to draw multiple lines in one case (and thus creating a triangle)

Of course. Just call `drawLine` 3 times, with the coordinates of a triangle. **Don't forget** the `break` statement in each of your `case`s.

> I also get this error message 1 error found

You don't have all of your necessary imports, or you have a typo in the source code. Are you sure `Graphics()` is spelled with an upper-case letter?

> how would i be able to fill in the Oval and Rectangle etc with a solid color.

Use `fillRectangle` and/or `fillOval` APIs.